# How to introduce dynamic_bitset in a struct

Tags: c++, struct, boost-dynamic-bitset

I tried to use `dynamic_bitset` in a structure. The size of `u` depends on the input.

```
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

struct myStruct
{
    double x;
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> u();
    myStruct( double a, boost::dynamic_bitset<>& v ) : x( a ), u( v ) {}
    {
        // some lines here
    }
};
```

However, I get the following error while compiling the code:

```
error: class ‘myStruct’ does not have any field named ‘u’
```

How can I solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `u` as a function prototype (i.e. a function returning a `dynamic_bitset`) rather than a member variable.

Change:

```
boost::dynamic_bitset<> u();
```

to:

```
boost::dynamic_bitset<> u;
```

Comment: Thank you @Paul-R, that solved my problem. Now, after compiling, it gives error `boost::dynamic_bitset<Block, Allocator>::~dynamic_bitset() [with Block = long unsigned int; Allocator = std::allocator<long unsigned int>]: Assertion 'm_check_invariants()' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)` after some iterations. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry - I'm not too familiar with `boost::dynamic_bitset` - it sounds like perhaps something got corrupted internally - maybe try running under valgrind ?